# Dynamic blog post carousel with Elementor Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to build a dynamic blog post carousel as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2t9W.png).
On the right side there should be a carousel with the blog posts and on the left side there should be more information about the active post in the carousel. Can I do this with Elementor's Loop Carousel?